# groupby filter for accounts where monthly balance are all negative

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Here is my sample data -

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Account': ['A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A2', 'A2', 'A2', 'A3', 'A3', 'A3', 'A3'],
                   'Date': ['D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4'],
                   'Month': ['M1', 'M1', 'M2', 'M2', 'M1', 'M1', 'M2', 'M2', 'M1', 'M1', 'M2', 'M2'],
                   'Balance': [133, 321, 123, 234, 345, 344, 456, -765, -123, -312, 111, -766]})

print(df)

   Account Date Month  Balance
0       A1   D1    M1      133
1       A1   D2    M1      321
2       A1   D3    M2      123
3       A1   D4    M2      234
4       A2   D1    M1      345
5       A2   D2    M1      344
6       A2   D3    M2      456
7       A2   D4    M2     -765
8       A3   D1    M1     -123
9       A3   D2    M1     -312
10      A3   D3    M2      111
11      A3   D4    M2     -766
```

I want to filter out accounts from this `df` where *all* monthly balances for an account is less than 0. In the example, only `A3` should get filtered out as all monthly balances for that account is less than 0.

Here is what I tried which does the job -

```
eod_gr = (df.groupby(['Account', 'Month'])['Balance'].mean() < 0).reset_index()
tmp = eod_gr.groupby('Account')['Balance'].all().to_dict()
accounts = [i for i in tmp if not tmp[i]]
print(accounts)
df_eod = df[df['Account'].isin(accounts)]
print(df_eod)
```

The problem is I am working on a real time use case where speed is paramount. I need a way to optimize this query to attain the same results.

**Expected Output**

```
  Account Date Month  Balance
0      A1   D1    M1      133
1      A1   D2    M1      321
2      A1   D3    M2      123
3      A1   D4    M2      234
4      A2   D1    M1      345
5      A2   D2    M1      344
6      A2   D3    M2      456
7      A2   D4    M2     -765
```

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think here should be improved performance omit by second groupby, here is used [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `'invert'` mask from `<` to `>=` for get all `accounts`:

```
mask = df.groupby(['Account', 'Month'])['Balance'].transform('mean') >= 0
accounts = df.loc[mask, 'Account']
df_eod = df[df['Account'].isin(accounts)]
print(df_eod)
  Account Date Month  Balance
0      A1   D1    M1      133
1      A1   D2    M1      321
2      A1   D3    M2      123
3      A1   D4    M2      234
4      A2   D1    M1      345
5      A2   D2    M1      344
6      A2   D3    M2      456
7      A2   D4    M2     -765
```

Another idea with aggregation `mean` and filter `MultiIndex Series` with [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
s = df.groupby(['Account', 'Month'])['Balance'].mean()
accounts = s.index[s >= 0].get_level_values(0)
df_eod = df[df['Account'].isin(accounts)]
```

Comment: any explanations for the speed boost? Is it because of avoiding multiple groupby?

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan - Give me a sec.